# Is there a convenient way to change the brightness at night in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, brightness

I know the settings menu, but is there some more convenient way (maybe with an addon)?

Comment: do you want to change it manually, or automatically by time of day?

Comment: @Pisu I think manually. What are the solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have applications like *RedShift*, but a very simple solution would be to put two (or more) screen brightness settings under a key combination:

1. *find out your screen name*: run in a terminal `xrandr`, it creates an output, starting like like:

   ```
   DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DVI-I-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   ```

   The one that is followed by "connected" is your screen name (in this case `DVI-I-1`)
2. Now add a command and a key combination of your preference to dim the screen (`System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts`). The command you need to add:

   ```
   xrandr --output <your_screenname> --brightness 0.8
   ```
3. Add aonother command that sets the brightness to 1 again:

   ```
    xrandr --output <your_screenname> --brightness 1
   ```

If you set these commands under (e.g.) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, you can dim / reset the screen brightness with two simple key combinations.

**Option 2: if you would make it automatically**

1. Create two simple scripts:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   xrandr --output <your_screenname> --brightness 0.8
   ```

   and

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   xrandr --output <your_screenname> --brightness 1
   ```
2. Create a directory `~/bin`, paste the scripts in an empty textfile, save them in `~/bin`as `dim_screen` and `reset_screen` (without extension) and make them both executable.
3. Install *Alarm Clock* (from the repositories). Set one or more alarm times, but instead of running an alarm, you can make it run a (single) command (called: "Start Application"). Use as commands:

   ```
   dim_screen
   ```

and

```
    reset_screen
```

(The same as the names of the scripts)